# Can every field extension be given via some irreducible polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying irreducible polynomials PIDs etc.

I have seen that a field extension of $k$ is $K$ comes from injective ring morphism$$k\hookrightarrow K$$

Also seen that if $k$ is a field and $f(x)\in k[x]$ which is irreducible.

Since $k[x]$ is PID and $(f)$ is prime (in UFDs irreducible elements are primes )

then $K:=\dfrac{k[x]}{(f)}$ is field.

I wonder that because of the first point given above, every field extension can be given, as a quotiened by a irreducible element from polynomial ring?

Comment: The answer is no. It may well happen that $[K:k]=\infty$, when this simple construction is clearly impossible. This is automatic when there are transcendental elements, but it can happen with algebraic extensions as well. A different problem appears in positive characteristic $p>0$, where we have example of extensions $L/K$ of degree $p^2$  such that every element of $L$ has a minimal polynomial of degree $\le p$. There are examples of all of these on the site. Search with buzzwords like *infinite algebraic extension*, *transcendental*, *algebraic extension that is not simple*.

Comment: The field of algebraic numbers (complex numbers algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$) is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ given by no irreducible polynomial. For that matter, so is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Take $k = \mathbb{Q}$. We can construct extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ by adjoining to $\mathbb{Q}$ some element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{C}$ which is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ but is not in $\mathbb{Q}$. One can show that this simple field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$, where $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$. In this sense, lots of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be thought of as quotients of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

However, if $\alpha$ is transcendental, then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ for any element $f(x)$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, by definition of being transcendental. $\pi$ is one such element of $\mathbb{C}$.